# GOOGLE SHEET IGNORE #REF

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I m working on a project on GOOGLE SHEET and I solve all of my problems, except one.

I have many Sheets which are called between different pages.

I need to recover all the data of any pages created, who have specific name.
Like : ='io208'!E28 // ='io308'!E28 // ='io408'!E28 // ETC...

The things is, all of theses pages are not created so I have to take all value but if I do a sum, some informations are missing (coz not createad) and the RESULT of my sum is #ref!

If someone have a idea..

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Try wrapping your range references in `iferror()`. See [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/13045193) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

try IFERROR before SUM:

```
=SUM(IFERROR({io208!E28, io308!E28, io408!E28}))
```